# WCF DataService alternatives to increase maxReceivedMessageSize

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

I'm currently facing the `(413) Request Entity Too Large` Error while trying to save entities to the Database. I've found out that this can be solved by increasing `maxReceivedMessageSize` value in the config. Aren't there other solutions to this? I was thinking of checking the request size before committing to the DB but couldn't find a way to do that. I also thought about calling `SaveChanges` periodically but then I would lose the transaction advantages....

Any Advise?

**EDIT**

What I'm doing is basically composing one entity, a lot of `AddToTable` `AddRelatedObject`and `SetLink` calls and finally save it all by calling `context.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions.Batch)`

If this helps...

Comment: "I was thinking of checking the request size before committing to the DB"

I don't think this is relevant, `maxReceivedMessageSize` only applies to the http messages. But maybe that's not what you meant.

How are you calling SaveChanges(), you are using the batch option yes? Perhaps provide the code of what you are trying to push in your scope for specific ideas, I'm not sure there's a general solution except maybe DTC but that's just awfully messy

Comment: I cannot post the code it would be far to much... But I've add the Information I've added helps out...

Comment: I know it's not your question, but _why_ are you seeking another solution? Apparently, your messages are big, so why not setting a bigger message size? If you are afraid of high server load (RAM usage _will_ be a problem after a few 100M with default setting), try setting your TransferMode to `Streamed` or `StreamedRequest`. I must say I never tried it with DataServices though, so not sure it really works with SaveChangesOptions.Batch

Comment: My concern is, how can I make sure it happens again? How do I permanently handle this limitation? And the other point, MS did it limit to prevent DoS attacks if I increase it will that be an issue? although our DataService isn't available from the Web

Comment: Well I can now say, the reason why I'm looking for another solution is I can't get it working.....

Comment: Ah. Did you set `readerQuotas` as well? If you are not on streaming you might also need to set `maxBufferSize`

Comment: I've just tried that yes... I've opened another question for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48517725/entity-famework-data-service-as-a-windows-service-how-to-change-maxreceivedmessa